# change spring root url name

Tags: java, spring, configuration

I have a little problem with a web application.

I'm using [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/) with a glassfish 3.1 server, and having problems with the start url

It start with:

```
http://localhost:9090/com.mkyong.common_SpringMVC_war_1.0-SNAPSHOT/login
```

when its supposed(I want to) start with:

```
http://localhost:9090/SpringMVC/login
```

I don't know exactly what/where to change it(not sure if it's maven config or web.xml)

this is my `web.xml` file

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-database.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and this my `pom.xml` file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mkyong.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringMVC</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringMVC Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL database driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>SpringMVC</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I thank your help and patience in advance

Comment: What is the name of the war file that is generated, and how are you deploying it?

Comment: the name of the file seem correct(SpringMVC.war) but when it is deployed(using netbenas 7.0.1, the application starts with the snapshot name)

Comment: looks like an netbeans issue (try to run maven `mvn package` from the command line. And then deploy the war, that is hopefully called `(SpringMVC.war`, by hand. If this works, that it is more likely a netbeans (configuration) issue.

Comment: @Ralph it seems to be that, thanks anyways

Answer (score 2):

Use context-root property of your glassfish-application.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-application PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Java EE Application 6.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-application_6_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-application>
 <web>
   <web-uri>hello.war</web-uri>
   <context-root>hi</context-root>
 </web>
 <security-role-mapping>
   <role-name>admin</role-name>
   <principal-name>js</principal-name>
   <group-name>manager</group-name>
 </security-role-mapping>
</glassfish-application>
```